# Trying to overwrite Amasty Checkout in custom theme Magento 2.2.7

Tags: magento2, module, theme, third-party-module, custom-theme

I'm trying to overwrite a file belonging to the Amasty Single Step Checkout from within my custom theme. The file I'm trying to overwrite is:

```
vendor/amasty/module-single-step-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/onepage/2columns.html
```

I'm trying to do so by creating a custom file in my theme:

```
design/frontend/MYVENDOR/MYTHEME/Amasty_Checkout/template/onepage/2columns.html
```

after clearing cache and deploying my theme it doesn't seem to work, wht am I missing?

I'm in developer mode

Comment: please remove this file from pub/static folder then check.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't seem to work

Comment: check my answer

Comment: check ans if it is working fine then accept . thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try This Below Code.

```
app/design/frontend/{MYVENDOR}/{MYTHEME}/frontend/Amasty_Checkout/web/template/onepage/2columns.html
```